# Delphi 7 - cxDBGrid Column : How to display a check mark next to some character string

Tags: delphi

I have to display in a cxdbGrid column 'Test √', and I got the check mark by using a symbol font but the rest of the characters changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common to include some type of image to represent the state of a column in a grid control. You could implement your own OnCustomDrawCellEvent to put an icon image there, instead of text and a font. Below is a link to a tutorial of how to accomplish this.

[How to draw an icon along with the text in a grid cell](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2936.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer if you do actually need to have the check as part of actual text in the text column.  I don't think I've ever seen an app that did it that way though.  The usual way of doing this is to add a column to the left or right of the text column in question and have the new column use a checkbox control.  Then just set the value of the checkbox column to true or false.

Comment: +1, in this case where the image is just a check mark I would go with this solution. Just add a field to the grid and set it Properties property to CheckBox.